# Problem with building the front-end-template

Tags: substrate

I am trying to install and use the React front end template for Substrate as per this [tutorial](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/interact), but when I run `yarn install` or `yarn start` in the project's root directory I get this error:

```
/home/.../substrate-front-end-template/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs:2
module.exports=(()=>{var e=

*blah blah blah*

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

I am using yarn v.1.22.11 and node v.8.10.0. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check versions of Yarn and NodeJS. On those versions on my end all works fine:

```
tomek@rhei-box:~/workspaces/substrate-front-end-template$ node -v
v12.22.4
tomek@rhei-box:~/workspaces/substrate-front-end-template$ yarn -v
2.4.0
```

In case you are on Linux-like machine check [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) tool in order to be able to change fast versions of NodeJS.